# physical Memory management in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working in a study application , I am getting all questions from webservice , after parsing I am creating objects of MyQuestion it's super class is NSObject and storing all the question object in a NSMutableArray also releases each question obj. , but the array contents sometimes  is more than 10,000 .

1. My doubt is , is it will create a memory issue as the array contacting huge objects.
2. Is there any better way to achieve same .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use instruments to see how big that array really is, and If it worries you, just don't download so much data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it will not. your memory leak will only be if you own an object and not release it. n the other thing that some time question is 1000, store them into db, and and fetch jst required ones

Answer (score 0):

1. It can become an issue simply because your app might run out of memory. But as **CodaFi** mentioned, you should use Instruments to check if this is actually the case.
2. You could store the data directly in a data base, such as *Core Data*, allowing you to only have a subset of your data in memory at any time. When using *Core Data*, you could use an `NSFetchedResultsController` or an `NSFetchRequest` with a `fetchLimit` to only fetch a subset of data or not all properties of a "question" into memory.